# Scala: return default value of a parameterized type

Tags: scala

Consider the following function in Scala:

```
def wrapMyFunction[A](foo: =>A):A = {
    try {
        foo
    }
    catch { case e => 
        //Return whatever the "empty" or "default" instance of type A would be,
        //such as 0, "", None, List(), etc.
    }
}
```

Given the type parameter A, how do I get the "empty" or "default" value of the type A? Is it even possible?

Comment: Sometimes `_` can stand for "default value" however I'm not sure if that would work in the case of generics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, technically, it is not possible, for the simple reason that there isn't such a thing as a "default" value.

The examples you give are all monoidal zeros, so, with Scalaz, you could write this:

```
def wrapMyFunction[A : Zero](foo: =>A):A = {
  ...
  catch { case e: Exception => // do not catch all throwables!
    implicitly[Zero[A]].zero
  }
}
```

Another alternative would be to instantiate a value. You can use a `ClassManifest` or a `ClassTag` (Scala 2.10.0) for that. For example:

```
def wrapMyFunction[A : scala.reflect.ClassTag](foo: => A): A = {
  ...
  catch { case e: Exception =>
    implicitly[scala.reflect.ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

That, however, depends on the existence of a parameterless constructor. Using a `ClassManifest` is pretty much the same.

Comment: Do you mean monoidal as opposed to monadic? Also, I'm pretty sure `Zero` has been removed from scalaz-seven - you'd have to have a `Monoid` instance available.

Comment: @KristianDomagala I do, sorry. Yes, I heard that `Zero` was no longer separate from `Monoid`, but Scalaz 7 isn't out yet.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, it's not generally possible without some type restriction on `A`. What about changing the method to take a default value, either explicitly or implicitly:

```
def wrapMyFunction[A](foo: =>A, fallback: =>A):A = ...
```

or

```
def wrapMyFunction[A](foo: =>A)(implicit fallback:A):A = ...
```